# Best method to build nested loops in Amazon Redshift SQL?

Tags: sql, for-loop, amazon-redshift, nested-loops, database-cursor

I'm new to Amazon Redshift, so I will try to use the correct the to terminology to my best knowledge, but bear with me:

I have branched data-set (data nested within data, imagine a "tree" that has "big Branch, that has smaller branches, etc., up until the "leaf" - which is the end. I need iterate through every single "branch" up until its' "leaf" and display it in another place.

The MAIN QUESTION is what method should I use to make a loop within a loop that would go "branch" to "branch" until it reaches the "leaf", go to next branch and repeat the process until reach the last leaf? I think I will need to store the first, second,... branch names somewhere in order to be able to go jump to the next branch once completed with previous one.

Here are the possible solutions I can think of

- Nested FOR LOOPs? (I tried but don't think sql gets along with nested for loops)
- WHILE LOOPs?
- Cursor? (currently trying to implement, but not sure is the best for performance)
- Create virtual table to store branch names, etc?
- Any other recommendations?

Comment: You are dealing with, I assume, relational data inside a database. We never loop a relational set. Or... we would only loop as a last-ditch effort, and a very rare one at that. Instead we want to use a set-based approach when dealing with the data, since that's exactly why we are using a database in the first place. Your data sounds hierarchical in nature. Generally we would store with a minimum of a single table with two columns `id | parent_id`. Then we use a "Recursive CTE" as the set based approach for traversing that hierarchy to get to your `leaf` from any given start point.

Comment: You can read up more on Recursive CTE's on Redshifts documentation site. They have an example as well, which may help with understanding the concept: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html

Comment: I'll second what @JNevill said - recursive CTEs